# Vue.js page inside iframe not showing on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, iframe

We have a Vue.js page contains a Echarts pie draft, and we want to show it in another project, which is using jQuery.
It shows perfectly both on Chrome and IE, but on Firefox there's nothing showing.
We tried to replace the Echarts page with some basic numbers in the template, but it's still empty in Firefox.
This is what it looks like in chrome:
[image]

And this is Firefox, which only has an empty app tag:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

*edit:*
I'm using Firefox93 on 64bit, there are no errors showing in the console.
This is how we inserted the iframe:
[image]

Comment: Are there any errors on firefox? Which version of firefox is it? And can you please provide code of how you implemeted your chart in the other project?

Comment: @StevenSiebert Yeah sure! I've edited my answer, please take a look!

Comment: If I were you, I would go to iframe URL (src attribute) and see if there are any JavaScript errors in Firefox JavaScript console.

Comment: @tGilvonas Just checked it, no errors appeared.

Comment: Hello @Yukiteru, were you finally able to fix this issue? I'm currently experiencing it too and this time, it's happening across different browsers.

Comment: Do not post code images but rather actual text code.

Comment: Hi @Benneee_ , sorry for replying this late. It might be too late but unfortunately we never find a way to fix it. We just made a new page with Vue.js to replace the jQuery one.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Yukiteru

No worries. I'm testing an implementation I made recently, If it does work out, I'll drop a comment or an answer here.

Comment: For me its seems javascript is not executed for some reason in the iframe

Answer (score 3):

Is the website you're trying to load the iframe in secure (https)?
I see you're trying to iframe an http url

Unlike HTTP images in an HTTPS page, which are allowed through with a little warning on the padlock, iframes are considered potentially dangerous active content and HTTP iframes won't be loaded into an HTTPS page.

Besides that the [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) policy might have something to do with it

Comment: Hiya John! I don't think this is the issue. For me, no error shows in the console and it only happens very occasionally, It's not even reproducible.
What I do notice anytime it happens is that the `data-v-app` attribute that shows on the "#app div" when a vue application has completely mounted is not added, like the mount process is incomplete. Do you understand?

Comment: Hi John, we switched to another plan at the end since we never figured it out, but I don't think the HTTP is the case, they were both HTTP pages. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: Have you tried my suggested solution? @Yukiteru Let me know if it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to several browsers is working well, and when opened in another browser it has something wrong, It should be the Web API or Browser API used by the library, in this case, VueJS.

The possible solutions from the estimated source of the problem are:

1. Update the VueJS to the latest version.
2. I hope this forum is useful: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/iframes-in-vue/102268, the questionnaire has a problem with its source link. But I think you are not experiencing this. And it is useful for anyone who visited this question.
3. If the problem is to be solved, I recommended using other people's custom libraries, like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-iframes. Because those libraries are developed to answer several problems that the creator facing that probably other people would be experiencing too.